# Integration Involving Tan[y/x]

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I was thinking this should be a straightforward Integration for `Mathematica`.
Solve for `y` in `dy/dx`=`Tan[y/x]` . Where `y` is a function of `x` (of course).I tried `DSolve`

```
DSolve[y'[x] == Tan[y[x]/x], y[x], x]
```

output looks like this

```
Solve[Integrate[(1/(K-Tan[K])),{K, 1, y[x]/x}] == C-Log[x], y[x]]
```

Is there a better way to evaluate the integral without necessarily specifying Initial condition? Still a newbie to `Mathematica`.Thanks

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that `dy/dx=Tan[y/x]` has an analytical solution?

Comment: It's basically giving you the solution using the standard trick for homogeneous ODEs that leads to a separable equation.  The problem is that the integral (for `u[x] == x y[x]`) cannot be found in finite terms.

Comment: I was not sure what I will get, I suspected there may not be an analytical solution, but since, I am new to the software, I was thinking the experienced folks in the house may have some answers. How should I go about this numerically? Thanks @bbgodfrey and Michael E2.

Comment: For what it's worth, for me (on Mma 11) the above DSolve doesn't seem to terminate, at least not within ten minutes or so. Sure, you can do a numerical solution, but then you need to supply an initial condition, such as `NDSolve[{y'[x] == Tan[y[x]/x], y[Pi/2] == 1}, y[x], {x, Pi/2, 3 Pi}]`

Comment: @Pirx  11.0 does yield the result in the question, but doing so takes several minutes.

Comment: @Pirx, thanks for the suggestion. A numerical solution does exist.